# Exporting a tibble with class "tbl_df/tbl/data.frame" as csv in R

Tags: r, tibble

[image]

I have a tibble in the format as that of the image. Its an output of the random forest executed on a grouped or nested data-frame. The class of the tibble is "tbl_df/ tbl/data.frame". When I am trying to export, it shoots an error 
"Error in write.table(df6_df, "df6_df.csv", row.names = F, col.names = TRUE,  :  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement' ".

The unlist() is extracting only the first list that belongs to one Subcat_ID, but there are many other SubCat_IDs which have such a list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like both the `data` and `fit` columns contain "nested data", i.e. each cell of those columns itself contains a multi-element data structure. Do you need to save those `data` and `fit` columns? If not, you can drop them and `write.table` will probably work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I had tried removing the data column. The fit column contains the predicted value for each Subcat_ID. The data has the variables for each Subcat_ID that were used in the prediction. Both of these columns are required.

Comment: In that case, you need to either "unnest" those columns to create a much longer dataframe with only one item per cell (`tidyr::unnest()` might help), or figure out how to extract a simple string representation of the required info in those columns.

Comment: I am currently using tidyr::unnest() function on data column and it works perfectly but throwing "Error: Input must be list of vectors" when I am trying to unnest the fit column. I am planning to try flatten() or squash() if that works.